# Customize th rendering in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

The DataTables plugin doesn't seems to permit to customize th rendering.

We can customize cell rendering at initialization using aTargets and mRender:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
    "aTargets": [transaction_id_index],
"mRender": function (data, type, row) {
    return 'custom '+data;
    }
}]
```

How can i do the same thing for table headers?

Note: I use Show and Hide feature so I can't modify directly the sTitle in aoColumns.

**EDIT**

I want to rename column title in order to minimize column width. I got sTitle like this: "foo_bar".
For now I am using this but it's not the best way for sure:

```
'fnInitComplete': function(oSettings, json){
    $(table).find("thead tr th").each(function(index) {
        $(this).html($(this).html().split("_").join("<br>"));
    });
},
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    // TO IMPROVE
    $(table).find("thead tr th").each(function() {
        if($(this).text().indexOf("_") !== -1) {
            $(this).html($(this).text().split("_").join("<br>"));                                        
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks @kabstergo for hints!
I don't close this question because my solution is not "clean".

Answer (score 2):

yes you can customize the header and footer, since nobody answered to you ill try to give you a start.
note: im no expert in the matter of how datatables work internally.

in our website here we have datatables with custom header. and this is made by doing this

```
var table = $('#my-datatable');
table.dataTable({
  ...
  'sDom': '<"dataTables_header"lfr>t<"dataTables_footer"ip>',
  'fnInitComplete': function(oSettings){
    // Style length select
    table.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_length select').addClass('select blue-gradient glossy').styleSelect();
    tableStyled = true;
  }
});
```

like i said, i hope it help you with something to start ...

Comment: That's a good start and better than modifying in another funtion! My problem is: With columns hidden (using "bVisible": false) at initialization. What is the best way to modify header when calling fnShowHide() function which toggle column visibility.

Answer (score 2):

In DataTables ^1.10, there is a [`headerCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/headerCallback) hook you can provide in the initialization options.

## Example

*(`$` is jQuery)*

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    headerCallback: function headerCallback(thead, data, start, end, display) {
        $(thead)
            .find('th')
            .first()
            .html('Displaying ' + (end - start) + ' records');
    }
});
```

Note that the first parameter might actually be the first `tr` inside the `thead`, not necessarily the `thead` element itself, contrary to what is stated in the DataTables documentation.

In complex scenarios with multiple header rows (`tr`s), you might need to select like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    headerCallback: function headerCallback(thead, data, start, end, display) {
        $(thead)
            .closest('thead')
            .find('th')
            .first()
            .html('Displaying ' + (end - start) + ' records');
    }
});
```